# Pandas dataframe to_json with nesting

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and Pandas. Want to create nested JSON with below sample data. I saw posts where we can use groupby and to_Json to create nested json. The Issue I'm facing is that the nested json gets created as arrays. I'm looking for both, in one case the endpoint I'm going to call expects arrays and in other cases it expects single record. I'm having trouble getting this to work.
Moreover, I have multiple such JSONs based on different dataframes and I would like to create generic method to create such json.

```
json_str = """[
{"StoreId" :111 ,
"StoreName" :"NeighbourhoodStore",
"City":"New Jersey",
"StreetAddress" :"23, Main Street",
"Zip" :12345,
"Monday"    :"9am - 6pm",
"Tuesday"   :"9am - 6pm",
"Wednesday" :"9am - 6pm",
"Thursday"  :"9am - 6pm",
"Friday"    :"9am - 6pm",
"Saturday"  :"10am - 5pm"},
{"StoreId" :112 ,
"StoreName" :"MainStreetStore",
"City":"New York",
"StreetAddress" :"1, Times Square",
"Zip" :12345,
"Monday"    :"9am - 9pm",
"Tuesday"   :"9am - 9pm",
"Wednesday" :"9am - 9pm",
"Thursday"  :"9am - 9pm",
"Friday"    :"9am - 9pm",
"Saturday"  :"10am - 5pm"}
]"""

data_list = json.loads(json_str)
```

Here is the expected output. Notice the OperationDays is array (I've not included all days there to keep it brief) whereas location is not array.

```
[
    {
        "StoreId": 111,
        "StoreName": "NeighbourhoodStore",
        "Location": {
            "City": "New York",
            "StreetAddress": "23, Main Street",
            "Zip": 12345
        },
        "OperationDays": [
            {
                "dayOfWeekName": "Monday",
                "hours": "9am-6pm",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "StoreId": 112,
        "StoreName": "MainStreet",
        "Location": {
            "City": "New York",
            "StreetAddress": "11 Times Square",
            "Zip": 11001
        },
        "OperationDays": [
            {
                "dayOfWeekName": "Tuesday",
                "hours": "9am-6pm",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see how we could take advantage of pandas in this case. You can however create a new dictionary list from `data_list` and export it to json:

```
new_list = []
days = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"}
location_keys = {"City", "StreetAddress", "Zip"}

for dic in data_list:
    new_dic = {}
    for k,v in dic.items():
        if k in days:
            new_dic.setdefault("OperationDays", []).append({"dayOfWeekName": k, "hours": v})
        elif k in location_keys:
            new_dic.setdefault("Location", {})[k] = v
        else:
            new_dic[k] = v
    new_list.append(new_dic)

print(json.dumps(new_list, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "StoreId": 111,
        "StoreName": "NeighbourhoodStore",
        "Location": {
            "City": "New Jersey",
            "StreetAddress": "23, Main Street",
            "Zip": 12345
        },
        "OperationDays": [
            {
                "dayOfWeekName": "Monday",
                "hours": "9am - 6pm"
            },
            {
                "dayOfWeekName": "Tuesday",
                "hours": "9am - 6pm"
            },
            {
                "dayOfWeekName": "Wednesday",
                "hours": "9am - 6pm"
            },
            {
                "dayOfWeekName": "Thursday",
                "hours": "9am - 6pm"
            },
            {
                "dayOfWeekName": "Friday",
                "hours": "9am - 6pm"
            },
            {
                "dayOfWeekName": "Saturday",
                "hours": "10am - 5pm"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "StoreId": 112,
        "StoreName": "MainStreetStore",
        "Location": {
            "City": "New York",
            "StreetAddress": "1, Times Square",
            "Zip": 12345
        },
        "OperationDays": [
            {
                "dayOfWeekName": "Monday",
                "hours": "9am - 9pm"
            },
            {
                "dayOfWeekName": "Tuesday",
                "hours": "9am - 9pm"
            },
            {
                "dayOfWeekName": "Wednesday",
                "hours": "9am - 9pm"
            },
            {
                "dayOfWeekName": "Thursday",
                "hours": "9am - 9pm"
            },
            {
                "dayOfWeekName": "Friday",
                "hours": "9am - 9pm"
            },
            {
                "dayOfWeekName": "Saturday",
                "hours": "10am - 5pm"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks @Tranbi for your response. I'm not sure if its possible to achieve with something similar to this?  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/67578/export-pandas-dataframe-to-a-nested-dictionary-from-multiple-columns

Comment: In the example you linked you can group by letters because they're repeating (they are also not dictionary keys). Your case is very different.

Comment: Hi @Tranvi, thanks for inputs. I've this problem that I need to transform many flat datasets to nested json. Is there any other way to achieve this without needing to write finctions? I was reading that scala case class can be used. But can I use structType to define schema and then transform the dataframe using that to convert to json?

Comment: I don't have experience with scala case class. You can ask a new question about that. I doubt it would be easier than writing a function that transforms your dictionary though.